# Redirect to another site with Authorization headers in ASP. Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, authorization

I am writing a simple ASP.Net application(Web Forms). I am trying to achieve when a user lands on my page I need to redirect them to another site page with Authorization JWT token. I am trying with below code.

```
 Response.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
 Response.Redirect("https://sitename/index.aspx");
 Response.End();
```

I can't see the Headers in the page or am I doing wrong?. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Response.Redirect, the header information is not passed to the new URL. 
The header which you have added before response.redirect, it would not be added to the new request.

There is limited support of adding new headers during Response.Redirect ONLY when your site is hosted in IIS ( v7 or more).

You can configure custom headers in the system.webServer configuration section.  These will be added when IIS redirects user to some URL.

I don't think we can put any dynamic value (e.g. user token).

***NOTE***: if you are transferring to another application owned by same organization (which is sharing infrastructure) then you can keep this bearer token in cache(where key will be a GUID) and then send GUID as a query string to other application.  The other application can read the query string and retrieve token from cache. Again this is subjected to High level design of your project/product.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```